# How to get executable's full target triple as a compile-time constant without using a build script?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I'm writing a Cargo helper command that needs to know the default target triple used by Rust/Cargo (which I presume is the same as host's target triple). Ideally it should be a compile-time constant.

There's [`ARCH`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/env/consts/constant.ARCH.html) constant, but it's not a full triple. For example, it doesn't distinguish between soft float and hard float ARM ABIs.

`env!("TARGET")` would be ideal, but it's set only for build scripts, and not the lib/bin targets. I could pass it on to the lib with `build.rs` and dynamic source code generation (writing the value to an `.rs` file in `OUT_DIR`), but it seems like a heavy hack just to get one string that the compiler has to know anyway.

Is there a more straightforward way to get the current target triple in lib/bin target built with Cargo?

Comment: The *host* is what platform is performing the compilation; the *target* is what platform the code will be executed on. You use these terms interchangeably; which do you need?

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm aware of the differences. Please note that I'm talking about building of a Cargo helper command, so the compilation target arch during helper's own compilation becomes the host arch once it's run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build scripts print some [additional output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script) to a file so you can not be sure that build script only printed output of `$TARGET`.

Instead, try something like this in build.rs:

```
fn main() {
    println!(
        "cargo:rustc-env=TARGET={}",
        std::env::var("TARGET").unwrap()
    );
}
```

This will fetch the value of the `$TARGET` environment variable in the build script and set it so it will be accessible when the program is started.

In my main.rs:

```
const TARGET: &str = env!("TARGET");
```

Now I can access the target triplet in my program. If you are using this technique, you'll only read the value of the`TARGET` environment variable and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is exposed other than through a build script. A concise way to get the target triple without "dynamic source code generation" would be, in `build.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    print!("{}", std::env::var("TARGET").unwrap());
}
```

and in `src/main.rs`:

```
const TARGET: &str = include_str!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/../output"));

fn main() {
    println!("target = {:?}", TARGET);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot `include_str!` exists. So that is marginally more straightforward than `include!`, but still uses `OUT_DIR`, so not as nice as I hoped.

Comment: Starting from Rust 1.19.0, you could supply the env var in build.rs as `println!("cargo:rustc-env=TARGET={}", var("TARGET").unwrap())`, and read it in main.rs as `const TARGET: &str = env!("TARGET");`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this, Shnatsel made a crate that worked really well for me. Uses the same method as the accepted answer but doesn't muddy up your build.rs since it's a crate. Provides Target Triple and Compiled-on Host Triple.

Lots of downloads, so I must be the only person who had trouble finding it, so I'm adding it here for posterity (:

https://crates.io/crates/current_platform

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know which target is installed, run: `rustup target list --installed`