# How do you conditionally compile based on a target triple?

Tags: compilation, rust, netbsd

Is it possible to conditionally compile for a specific target triple? I’m having issues with excluding the `x86_64-rumprun-netbsd` target without simply excluding `netbsd` with a `#[cfg]`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Is there a list of all cfg features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742046/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: no, there is no `cfg` for the target triple.

Comment: See also [How to get executable's full target triple as a compile-time constant without using a build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48967583/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster it looks like the target_vendor configuration might be useful for me. But there is no list of valid target_vendors

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `target_vendor` configuration, which has a value for `rumprun` as described in [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/28593). In general, you can use any of the target vendors from [this page](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Triple.html#details), as described in [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/28612).